# Is there a way to add quotes to a multi paragraph string

Tags: string, escaping

I wrote the following line:

```
 string QuoteTest2 = "Benjamin Netnayahu,\"BB\", said that: \"Israel will not fall\"";
```

This example went well, but what can I do in case I want to write a multi paragraph string including quotes?

The following example shows that puting '@' before the doesn't cut it..

```
    string QuoteTest2 = @"Benjamin Netnayahu,\"BB\", said that: \"Israel will not fall\"";
```

The string ends and the second quote and the over just gives me errors, what should I do?

Comment: What language is this? Could you add the appropriate tag please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes to escape ""

e.g.

```
string QuoteTest2 = @"Benjamin Netnayahu,""BB"", said that: ""Israel will not fall""";
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another quoestion..
I wrote:
`            Regex FindQuotes = new Regex("(:|,)\\s[\"]([^\"_-]{2,})[\"][,]? ");

            string QuoteTest2 = @"Benjamin Netnayahu, ""BB\"", said that: ""Israel will not fall""";
            MatchCollection matches = FindQuotes.Matches(QuoteTest2);
            foreach (Match m in matches)
                Console.WriteLine(m.Value);`
The only match was: , "BB",
but : "Israel will not fall"  was not matched..why?

Comment: Start a new question, someone might be better able to answer.